# How to find the angular velocity vector given the velocity, radius and acceleration vectors?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, calculus

How do I calculate the angular velocity vector about the origin, given the position, velocity and acceleration vectors?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is homework. This question is simply asking the relationship between angular velocity, position, velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

The angular velocity (pseudo-)vector is defined as
$$\boldsymbol{\omega} = \frac{\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}}{r^2}$$
where $\mathbf{r}$ is position and $\mathbf{v}$ is velocity.